# Redirect an Apache2 SSL VirtualHost with mod_alias

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect, mod-alias

I want to make sure there aren't any mysterious odd behaviors when redirecting a SSL VirtualHost with [mod_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) `Redirect` as [outlined by Apache here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/remapping.html#canonicalhost).

My code seems to work, but since SSL virtual hosts are restricted to just one IP address, I want to make sure there aren't any problems eluding me. Explicitly not using TLS. I'm stuck with Apache 2.2 for now.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /path/to/example.com-crt.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/example.com-key.key
    SSLCACertificateFile /path/to/example.com-ca.txt
    Redirect 301 / https://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.example.com
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /path/to/example.com-crt.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/example.com-key.key
    SSLCACertificateFile /path/to/example.com-ca.txt
    # Do stuff
</VirtualHost>
```

So my question is, should SSL VirtualHost redirection with mod_alias `Redirect` work the same as non-SSL redirection?

**UPDATE:** To be clear, I want to make sure the `Redirect` circumvents the need for SNI/TLS, especially related to IE6 on WinXP. Seems to work fine in my tests with IE6 on WinXP-SP3 (see comments below the answer marked correct).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it works the same.

x509v3 includes *Subject Alternative Name*. Most (all?) issuing CA's will list both `www.example.com` and `example.com` as equivalent alternate names in a cert requested for either. Because of this browsers won't choke on the name when using the same cert in both VirtualHost instances.

---

On a different note, you have:

```
Redirect 301 / http://www.example.com/
```

I would instead recomend:

```
Redirect 301 / https://www.example.com/
```

Because this *is* SSL after all.

Comment: Oops, fixed! So there are no issues with turning the SSL Engine on the same IP address in two VirtualHosts as long as one is a redirect? Sort of goes against everything I've read, but it seems to work fine. Guess I'm just looking for some confidence before putting this into production.

Comment: It should work on any relevant browser and OS. I believe Internet Explorer on Windows XP doesn't support Server Name Indication, so in that case I think it will throw you on the first virtualhost in your configuration (which is what you probably read everywhere).

Comment: I just tested with IE6 on WinXP-SP3 and it works fine. I'm a little surprised myself. I don't think SNI/TLS comes into play because of the redirect -- that was the core of my question. Would love it if someone else can confirm my findings.

Comment: SNI/TLS doesn't come into play. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. For any future visitors to this question who might be curious, I can confirm that my cert does indeed include both `www.` and no-`www.` listings.

Comment: @Jeff: Yeah, I can't even remember the last time one I got didn't have it.